# メンバ変数からのインスタンス特定について

Tags: java

メンバ変数からその変数が保存されているインスタンスを特定したいです。例えば以下のようなインスタンスを作ったとしてStudentID 1からインスタンス名のsample1又はSample1の他のメンバ変数を特定することはできますか？

```
class Student{
    int studentID;
    String name ;
    int age ;
}
Student sample1 = new Student(1,“太郎”,14);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Sample1の他のメンバ変数を特定することはできますか？

HashMapでStudentのインスタンスを管理すればいいのではないでしょうか。

[Java | HashMapの使い方](https://www.javadrive.jp/start/collection/index3.html#section6)

HashMapのキーをStudentID、値をStudentのインスタンスにすれば、getメソッドでStudentIDからインスタンスを参照できます。当然ですが、Studentクラスでメンバ変数のgetterを実装しておく必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

HashMapでStudentのインスタンスを管理をお勧めします。

こんなのはどうでしょうか。

コンストラクタをprivate にしてfactoryメソッドでのみインスタンスを作成できるようにする。
factoryメソッドで、インスタンスを管理するようにする。
インスタンス情報を知りたければ、getStudentメソッドを利用する。

```java
public class Student {
    Integer studentId;
    String name ;
    int age ;

    private static Map<Integer, Student> studentMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Student(Integer studentId, String name, int age) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static Student factory(Integer studentId, String name, int age) {
        Student student = new Student(studentId, name, age);
        studentMap.put(studentId, student);
        return student;
    }
    public static Student getStudent(Integer studentId) throws Exception {
        if (studentMap.containsKey(studentId)) {
            return studentMap.get(studentId);
        }
        throw new Exception("インスタンスはありません。");
    }

}
```